# Getting top 3 values from multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-level grouped pandas dataframe which looks something like this:

```
date          AccountNum       ProgramName     Duration
2017-11-12    12345            program1          200
                               program2          300
                               program4          100
                               program5          250
              45678            program7          200
                               program2          300
                               program8          100
                               program5          250

  .... more accounts for 2017-11-12

2017-11-18    12345            program6          200
                               program2          300
                               program3          100
                               program5          250 
              45678            program6          200
                               program3          300
                               program4          100
                               program5          250
etc-etc
```

The duration is aggregated already, it is an average by the date, by account number, and by program name. 
Here was the code to get the dataframe above:

```
grouped = programs.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W'),'AccNum','ProgramName'])['Duration'].agg('mean')
```

The Duration column is the average per week for each account (and for each week).
I need to select top 3 programs for each account per week.

I tried nlargest() function but it does not seem to be working for me because I am either getting only 3 accounts back or losing the date column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is what I want the result to look like:

```
    date          AccountNum       ProgramName     Duration
    2017-11-12    12345            program2          300
                                   program5          250
                                   program1          200
                  45678            program2          300
                                   program5          259
                                   program7          200

      .... more accounts for 2017-11-12

    2017-11-18    12345            program2          300
                                   program5          250
                                   program6          200
                  45678            program3          300
                                   program5          250
                                   program6          200
 .... more dates and more accounts ..
```

Essentially, I need to keep the group structure -- by date/by account/top 3 programs based on duration. The end goal of this exercise is to be able to see the change in duration week after week for top 3 programs for each account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [143]: df.groupby(level=[0,1], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3, columns=['Duration'])).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out[143]:
                      ProgramName  Duration
date       AccountNum
2017-11-12 12345.0       program2       300
           12345.0       program5       250
           12345.0       program1       200
           45678.0       program2       300
           45678.0       program5       250
           45678.0       program7       200
2017-11-18 12345.0       program2       300
           12345.0       program5       250
           12345.0       program6       200
           45678.0       program3       300
           45678.0       program5       250
           45678.0       program6       200
```

Comment: Thank you, @MaxU. Something like this, but I need to keep the Program Name. Also, I don't need 2 Account Number columns but I guess I can drop one after I reset index. Can I return the Program Name as well?

Comment: @IrinaS, can you post your desired data set in your question?

Comment: updated the question. I  need to be able to see the change in duration for each program within the account and within the date range which in my case - 1 week. Makes sense? @MaxU, Thanks for helping!

Comment: thank you for your answers, @MaxU! Can you please add back the previous solution? I want to try both and see which one brings me closer to what I need? Thank you!!

Comment: @IrinaS, you can see the history of edits - press on "edited XXX ago" under the answer...

Comment: To provide an update: this last suggestion worked the magic, except I was still losing the Date column. Just to move past this point, I had to remove drop=True in the end and then separately drop 'level_0' column. Not sure if there is a better solution, but I needed to move past this point. Thanks for your help @MaxU.